# Potential null pointer access: The variable stream may be null at this location

Tags: java, android, eclipse, function

I received this error in this function and do not know exactly how to solve.
"Potential null pointer access: The variable stream may be null at this location"
Below is the code:

```
public void downloadAudioIncrement(String mediaUrl) throws IOException {
        /*URLConnection cn = new URL(mediaUrl).openConnection(Proxy.NO_PROXY);  

        cn.connect();  
        InputStream stream = cn.getInputStream();*/
        URL url = new URL(mediaUrl);

        InputStream stream = url.openStream();
        //Toast.makeText(this.context, "here3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        if (stream == null) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Não é possível criar InputStream para a url: " + mediaUrl);
        }

        //downloadingMediaFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(),"downloadingMedia_" + (counter++) + ".dat");
        downloadingMediaFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(),"downloadingMedia_.dat");
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(downloadingMediaFile);   
        byte buf[] = new byte[16384];

        int totalBytesRead = 0, incrementalBytesRead = 0;
        do {
            int numread = ***stream***.read(buf);   
            if (numread <= 0)
                break;   

            out.write(buf, 0, numread);
            totalBytesRead += numread;
            incrementalBytesRead += numread;
            totalKbRead = totalBytesRead/1000;

            testMediaBuffer();
            fireDataLoadUpdate();
        } while (validateNotInterrupted());   

        if (validateNotInterrupted()) {
            fireDataFullyLoaded();
            //testMediaBuffer();
            //fireDataLoadUpdate();
        }
        ***stream***.close();
        out.close();
    }
```

How do I fix this error? The error occurs here:

```
 numread ***stream***.Read = int (buf);
```

and here:

```
 ***stream***.Close ();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if (stream == null) {
        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Não é possível criar InputStream para a url: " + mediaUrl);
    }
```

Here, you check if `stream` is `null`, and log it, but you still proceed with the method, and you never make a new `stream` or anything. My suggestion: add a `return;` to your block:

```
    if (stream == null) {
        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Não é possível criar InputStream para a url: " + mediaUrl);
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line to read

```
 if (stream == null) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Não é possível criar InputStream para a url: " +     mediaUrl);
return;
    }
```

that way, the erroneous lines won't be reached with a null value.